# How can I allow <source> tags through rails 4 sanitize?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, sanitize, actionviewhelper

I've been using the sanitize method in a Rails 4 app to scrub a page which displays html that users generate to prevent unsafe things like script injection. So I have a view that looks like:

```
sanitize @user_input
```

Right now I'm having issues when uses are entering video tags with a source tag under it like so:

```
<video><source src="foo.bar"></video>
```

Unfortunately it looks like sanitize is stripping out the source tag so videos are no longer working. How do I use sanitize so it allows source tags? Also how can I get a list of tags that are being allowed/dis-allowed? It'd be great to understand what is going under the hood.

Just to be fully clear, I'd like to be able to add the source tag to the whitelist. When I specify it as as an allowed tag in the arguments for sanitize it removes all the previous defaults for whitelisted tags. For example, I'd still like to allow default tags like a, h1, etc.

**How do I add source to the whitelist instead of completing replacing it?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After digging through the source I've found that the list of default elements allowed is based on Loofah's WhiteList Sanitize

- Defaults tags: `Loofah::HTML5::WhiteList::ALLOWED_ELEMENTS_WITH_LIBXML2`
- Default attributes: `Loofah::HTML5::WhiteList::ALLOWED_ATTRIBUTES`

So to add `<source>` to the default list you could the following:

```
default_tags = Loofah::HTML5::WhiteList::ALLOWED_ELEMENTS_WITH_LIBXML2.add('source')
default_attributes = Loofah::HTML5::WhiteList::ALLOWED_ATTRIBUTES
sanitize @user_input, tags: default_tags, attributes: default_attributes
```

Comment: On this official page, it clearly states `The default sanitizer is Rails::Html::WhiteListSanitizer. See Rails HTML Sanitizers for more information.
`, which is why I mentioned it on my answer. I guess there is something wrong with the documentation.

Comment: Yes that's correct but WhiteListSanitizer uses the Loofah gem so you have to dig further. The list of allowed tags and attributes in your answer are if you use sanitize and pass in a custom set of tags or attributes. For example, if you use santize and pass in attributes: src, the default tags become the list in your answer (since that's the fallback when its not set). If you dig through the source code you see there are 3 modes of sanitizing: 1) the default 2) with a custom scrubber 3) with a set attributes or tags. Unfortunately #1 & #3 have different defaults. Confusing!

Comment: `The list of allowed tags and attributes in your answer are if you use sanitize and pass in a custom set of tags or attributes.` That can't be the case because the moment you pass in `tags: %w(video source)`, `h1` tags get removed too, but `h1` is included in the whitelist that I gave. When you pass any tag or attribute as an argument, they completely replace the list. I don't know, there is something I'm missing maybe, and obviously as you said the list I provided doesn't include all the tags and attributes, but I'm done investigating for the moment :)

Comment: What if I want to add multiple attributes to the previously defined allowed attributes.

Answer (score 3):

By adjusting default whitelist:

```
attributes_whitelist = Rails::Html::Sanitizer.white_list_sanitizer.allowed_attributes
attributes_whitelist << 'source'
sanitize(@user_input, attributes: attributes_whitelist)
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper/sanitize.

You can supply an option hash with the tags you would like to whitelist like so:

```
sanitize('<video><source src="foo.bar"></video>', tags: %w(video source))
```

I can't find if there is a way to get the full whitelist from within the Rails app, but this is the source code of the default sanitizer that is used (check out the `WhiteListSanitizer` class):

https://github.com/rails/rails-html-sanitizer/blob/master/lib/rails/html/sanitizer.rb

From there you can see that the allowed tags are:

```
%w(strong em b i p code pre tt samp kbd var sub
    sup dfn cite big small address hr br div span h1 h2 h3 h4 h5 h6 ul ol li dl dt dd abbr
    acronym a img blockquote del ins)
```

and the allowed attributes are:

```
%w(href src width height alt cite datetime title class name xml:lang abbr)
```

You can add `video` and `source` to the tags list and provide it to the `sanitize` helper.

Comment: Thanks, but I was trying to add the source tag to the whitelist without completely replacing it. I've edited my question to reflect this. So for example previously it was not strippting out h1 tags but now it is. How can I add instead of replacing? Even better, how do I display the default whitelist tags and attributes? 
When I try ActionView::Base.sanitized_allowed_attributes in the console I  get back nil

Comment: Thanks for looking through the source code. Unfortunately, I don't believe that's the full list of allowed tags as sanitize is letting in the video tag and that is not on this list. I've been doing some digging and  I believe this is closer to the complete list: https://github.com/flavorjones/loofah/blob/master/lib/loofah/html5/whitelist.rb

I'm still digging to understand how sanitize works with Loofah but this is a start, thanks!

Comment: please checkout my answer if you want to see the full list of default tags and attributes

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

`<%= sanitize @user_input, tags: %w(video source), attributes: %w(src) %>`